# Do not include certain source files

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a folder containing all the log files, the filenames are colour-red, colour-green, colour-blue, colour-yellow, etc. I am writing the spl to include all the files except one, e.g. colour-white.

I know the * performs the wildcard search, and [^c] excludes specific character in the bracket. But I don't know how to combine them to exclude a certain word. On the other hand, I am not sure the same regrex rule apply for splunk.

```
source= "log/colour-*"
source= "log/colour-[^w]"
```

The desired result of the query is to retrieve all the files, expect colour-white.

Maybe some filters can be applied to retrieve the desired result, but so far the filters I know are for the file contents, not the file names.

Comment: If lookarounds are supported, you could use `\bcolour-(?!white\b)\w+` https://regex101.com/r/SUJ00U/1 Or else list all the allowed colors `\bcolour-(?:red|green|blue|yellow)\b`  https://regex101.com/r/aOBL8E/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use something like this in your search query,

```
source!="log/colour-white"
```

And you can also check the difference between `!=` and `NOT` at below link to get a more clear info on what to use.

[Splunk Answers](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/93873/difference-between-the-not-and-operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `search` command (the implicit command before the first `|`) does not support regex.  To exclude something, use `NOT`.

```
(source = "log/colour-*" NOT source = "log/colour-w*")
```